# Sum file sizes that are older than 7 years under a folder in Windows Server 2008

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2008, filesize, timestamp

I need to find the total size of all files that are older than 7 years, under a folder that has thousands of files.

Is there any quick way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FORFILES /D -23-03-2006 /C "cmd /c echo @fsize" > sizes.txt

set sz=0

for /f %a in (sizes.txt) do set /a sz=sz+%a

echo size: %sz%
```